# Fast subset/lookup/filter in large datasets

Tags: r, performance, dplyr, data.table, subset

I need to repeatedly look up "closest" row in a large (many GB) table with factor and numeric columns. Using `dplyr`, it looks like this:

```
df <- data.frame(factorA = rep(letters[1:3], 100000),
             factorB = sample(rep(letters[1:3], 100000), 
                              3*100000, replace = FALSE),
             numC = round(rnorm(3*100000), 2),
             numD = round(rnorm(3*100000), 2))

closest <- function(ValueA, ValueB, ValueC, ValueD) {
  df_sub <- df %>%
    filter(factorA == ValueA,
           factorB == ValueB,
           numC >= 0.9 * ValueC,
           numC <= 1.1 * ValueC,
           numD >= 0.9 * ValueD,
           numD <= 1.1 * ValueD)

  if (nrow(df_sub) == 0) stop("Oh-oh, no candidates.")

  minC <- df_sub[which.min(abs(df_sub$numC - ValueC)), "numC"]

  df_sub %>%
    filter(numC == minC) %>%
    slice(which.min(abs(numD - ValueD))) %>%
    as.list() %>%
    return()
}
```

Here is a benchmark of the above:

```
> microbenchmark(closest("a", "b", 0.5, 0.6))
Unit: milliseconds
                        expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval
 closest("a", "b", 0.5, 0.6) 25.20927 28.90623 35.16863 34.59485 35.25468 108.3489   100
```

What's the best way to optimize this function for speed? There's RAM to spare, even with the large `df` in memory, but given the many calls to this function, I would like to make it as fast as possible.

Would using a `data.table` instead of `dplyr` help?

---

Here are two optimizations I tried thus far:

```
dt <- as.data.table(df)

closest2 <- function(ValueA, ValueB, ValueC, ValueD) {
  df_sub <- df %>%
    filter(factorA == ValueA,
           factorB == ValueB,
           dplyr::between(numC, 0.9 * ValueC, 1.1 * ValueC),
           dplyr::between(numD, 0.9 * ValueD, 1.1 * ValueD))

  if (nrow(df_sub) == 0) stop("Oh-oh, no candidates.")

  minC <- df_sub[which.min(abs(df_sub$numC - ValueC)), "numC"]

  df_sub %>%
    filter(numC == minC) %>%
    slice(which.min(abs(numD - ValueD))) %>%
    as.list() %>%
    return()
}

closest3 <- function(ValueA, ValueB, ValueC, ValueD) {

  dt_sub <- dt[factorA == ValueA & 
                 factorB == ValueB & 
                 numC %between% c(0.9 * ValueC, 1.1 * ValueC) &
                 numD %between% c(0.9 * ValueD, 1.1 * ValueD)]

  if (nrow(dt_sub) == 0) stop("Oh-oh, no candidates.")

  dt_sub[abs(numC - ValueC) == min(abs(numC - ValueC))][which.min(abs(numD - ValueD))] %>%
    as.list() %>%
    return()
}
```

The benchmark:

```
> microbenchmark(closest("a", "b", 0.5, 0.6), closest2("a", "b", 0.5, 0.6), closest3("a", "b", 0.5, 0.6))
Unit: milliseconds
                         expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq       max neval cld
  closest("a", "b", 0.5, 0.6) 25.15780 25.62904 36.52022 34.68219 35.27116 155.31924   100   c
 closest2("a", "b", 0.5, 0.6) 22.14465 22.46490 27.81361 31.40918 32.04427  35.79021   100  b 
 closest3("a", "b", 0.5, 0.6) 13.52094 13.77555 20.04284 22.70408 23.41452 142.73626   100 a
```

Can this be optimized more?

Comment: What about getting the order indices of C and D and using a binary search?

Comment: How? I tried `setkey(dt, numC, numD)`, but it didn't seem to make a difference.

Comment: If you can look these up in parallel (with vectors of ValueA, ValueB, ValueC, ValueD instead of single values), I guess you'll be able to do it much faster than sequentially (which is apparently how you plan to go about doing this "repeatedly" since you're benchmarking that way).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @Frank. I can parallelize only to a limited extent (say, instead of calling the function a million times, call it 200,000 times with length 5 vectors of values). Given this, would parallelizing help?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you can call many tuples of values in parallel instead of sequentially...

```
set.seed(1)
DF <- data.frame(factorA = rep(letters[1:3], 100000),
             factorB = sample(rep(letters[1:3], 100000), 
                              3*100000, replace = FALSE),
             numC = round(rnorm(3*100000), 2),
             numD = round(rnorm(3*100000), 2))

library(data.table)
DT = data.table(DF)

f = function(vA, vB, nC, nD, dat = DT){

  rs <- dat[.(vA, vB, nC), on=.(factorA, factorB, numC), roll="nearest",
    .(g = .GRP, r = .I, numD), by=.EACHI][.(seq_along(vA), nD), on=.(g, numD), roll="nearest", mult="first", 
    r]

  df[rs]
}

# example usage
mDT = data.table(vA = c("a", "b"), vB = c("c", "c"), nC = c(.3, .5), nD = c(.6, .8))

mDT[, do.call(f, .SD)]

#    factorA factorB numC numD
# 1:       a       c  0.3 0.60
# 2:       b       c  0.5 0.76
```

Comparing with the other solutions that must be run rowwise...

```
# check the results match
library(magrittr)
dt = copy(DT)
mDT[, closest3(vA, vB, nC, nD), by=.(mr = seq_len(nrow(mDT)))]

#    mr factorA factorB numC numD
# 1:  1       a       c  0.3 0.60
# 2:  2       b       c  0.5 0.76

# check speed for a larger number of comparisons

nr = 100
system.time( mDT[rep(1:2, each=nr), do.call(f, .SD)] )
#    user  system elapsed 
#    0.07    0.00    0.06 

system.time( mDT[rep(1:2, each=nr), closest3(vA, vB, nC, nD), by=.(mr = seq_len(nr*nrow(mDT)))] )
#    user  system elapsed 
#   10.65    2.30   12.60
```

*How it works*

For each tuple in `.(vA, vB, nC)`, we look up rows that match `vA` and `vB` exactly and then "roll" to the nearest value of `nC` -- this doesn't quite match the OP's rule (of looking within a bound of nC*[0.9, 1.1]), but that rule could easily be applied after-the-fact. For each match, we take the tuple's "group number," `.GRP`, the row numbers that were matched, and the values of `numD` on those rows.

Then we join on group number and `nD`, matching exactly on the former and rolling to nearest on the latter. If there are multiple nearest matches, we take the first with `mult="first"`.

We can then take the row number of each tuple's match and look it up in the original table.

*Performance*

So the vectorized solution seems to have a big performance benefit, as usual with R.

If you can only pass ~5 tuples at a time (as for the OP) instead of 200, there will still probably be benefits from this approach vs `which.min` and similar, thanks to binary search, as @F.Privé suggested in a comment.

As noted in @HarlanNelson's answer, adding indices to the table might further improve performance. See his answer and `?setindex`.

*Fix for numC rolling to one value*

Thanks to the OP for identifying this problem:

```
DT2 = data.table(id = "A", numC = rep(c(1.01,1.02), each=5), numD = seq(.01,.1,.01))
DT2[.("A", 1.011), on=.(id, numC), roll="nearest"]
#    id  numC numD
# 1:  A 1.011 0.05
```

Here, we see one row, but we should be seeing five. One fix (though I'm not sure why) is converting to integers:

```
DT3 = copy(DT2)
DT3[, numC := as.integer(numC*100)]
DT3[, numD := as.integer(numD*100)]
DT3[.("A", 101.1), on=.(id, numC), roll="nearest"]
#    id numC numD
# 1:  A  101    1
# 2:  A  101    2
# 3:  A  101    3
# 4:  A  101    4
# 5:  A  101    5
```

Comment: Very nice! Could you explain `c(.(g = .GRP, r = .I), .SD), by=.EACHI]`? I'm afraid my `data.table` knowledge is quite limited (compared to `tidyverse`).

Comment: @Victor Thanks, I've now simplified that part and added an explanation. I didn't realize I didn't need .SD there, and have explained what .GRP and .I are. Let me know if anything else is unclear

Comment: I implemented your suggestion, and it's indeed fast. However, it has an undesired behavior: if the last value (`numC` in this case) is rolled, only a single match is returned even if there are multiple rows with the "rolled-to" value of numC. This breaks the second rolling join for `numD`: the selected single value from before can have `numD` very far from `nD`. Any ideas?

Comment: @Victor Oh, good point. If your numbers really are rounded to two digits, one workaround is to use integers instead (see edit to answer), though to me it seems like a bug, now posted here: https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/2444

Comment: Actually my numC is a date, but the same bug applies. I guess the workaround would be to "permanently" add another column converting numC to an integer and use that column in the rolling join. (My table doesn't change -- it's just a huge lookup table -- so adding another column is feasible.)

Comment: @Victor Another alternative might be to use integer-stored dates; see `?IDate`.

Answer (score 2):

This is cheating because I index before the benchmark, but I assume you will run the query many times on the same data.table.

```
library(data.table)
dt<-as.data.table(df)
setkey(dt,factorA,factorB)

closest2 <- function(ValueA, ValueB, ValueC, ValueD) {

  dt<-dt[.(ValueA,ValueB), on = c('factorA','factorB')]
  df_sub <- dt %>%
    filter( numC >= 0.9 * ValueC,
           numC <= 1.1 * ValueC,
           numD >= 0.9 * ValueD,
           numD <= 1.1 * ValueD)

  if (nrow(df_sub) == 0) stop("Oh-oh, no candidates.")

  minC <- df_sub[which.min(abs(df_sub$numC - ValueC)), "numC"]

  df_sub %>%
    filter(numC == minC) %>%
    slice(which.min(abs(numD - ValueD))) %>%
    as.list() %>%
    return()
}

library(microbenchmark)
microbenchmark(closest("a", "b", 0.5, 0.6))
microbenchmark(closest2("a", "b", 0.5, 0.6))


Unit: milliseconds
                       expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval
closest("a", "b", 0.5, 0.6) 20.29775 22.55372 28.08176 23.20033 25.42154 127.7781   100
Unit: milliseconds
                       expr      min       lq     mean   median      uq      max neval
 closest2("a", "b", 0.5, 0.6) 8.595854 9.063261 9.929237 9.396594 10.0247 16.92655   100
```

Comment: Maybe call it closest 2b or something to distinguish from OP's function called closest2? Btw, in my opinion it's not cheating as long as we assume the table key isn't broken between uses of the function.

Comment: Ah, so that's how you index! Thanks Harlan. Could indexing `numC` and `numD` produce even better results?